# adding element into the List with prolog

Tags: prolog

I got a problem with this 
I want to make a list of target position like if I type

```
?- extractIndices([5,6,7,8,9,5,6],6,List).
```

it should return

```
List = [1,6]
```

which gives all position of 6 in that list.
I wrote code like this:

```
extractIndices(List , Item, [Index | Indecis]) :- 
    indexOf(List , Item, Index).

indexOf([Item | _], Item, 0).
indexOf([_ |Tail], Item, Index):-
    indexOf(Tail, Item, Index1),
    Index is Index1+1.
```

and this gives me

```
?- extractIndices([5,6,7,8,9,5,6],6,L).
L = [1|_G2870] ;
L = [6|_G2870] ;
false.
```

It will be so thankful if someone can help me fix this... 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided two rules for `indexOf`, one which handles the *head* of the list, ignoring the tail, and one which handles the *tail*, ignoring the head.  This results in two different solutions to your query as shown.

The predicate `nth0` can be used to map positions to items in a list.

The easiest way to use it is going to be with `findall`:

```
extractIndices(List , Item, Indices) :-
     findall(N, nth0(N, List, Item), Indices).
```

You can also make your own solution using something like `indexOf`.  But you probably want to provide two different rules: one for the *base case* (usually an empty list), and one *recursive case* which solves it for the head, and then calls `indexOf` again on the tail.

Comment: Thank you for providing me findall function in prolog, it works really well & fast ,thank you . I did it as a practice for clearing my mind , is there any way just recursively do the list manipulation to find out result without using any in-buit functions?

Comment: Just pop up for anyone need this : findall(Object,Goal,List).
produces a list List of all the objects Object that satisfy the goal Goal. Often Object is simply a variable, in which case the query can be read as: Give me a list containing all the instantiations of Object which satisfy Goal.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same code as Edmund (i.e. findall + nth0), but for learning purpose a correction to your code it's worth to show:

```
extractIndices(List , Item, Indices) :- 
    indexOf(List, Item, 0, Indices).

indexOf([X|Items], Item, I, Is) :-
    ( X == Item -> Is = [I|Rs] ; Is = Rs ),
    J is I + 1,
    indexOf(Items, Item, J, Rs).
indexOf([], _, _, []).
```

test:

```
?- extractIndices([5,6,7,8,9,5,6],6,L).
L = [1, 6].
```

Comment: Thank you, this method is as good as Edmund, but helps me understanding prolog.:)